# Limit the events of a blob storage sent to azure function that triggers service bus queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azureservicebus

Here is my architecture:

- I have a blob storage with an event that triggers an azure function when a blob is created in a container.
- The azure function read the file (xml) and sent a message to a service bus queue depending on a xml tag in the file. It means that I have multiple queues in my service bus.
- An app that is running with multiple threads is then pulling the messages from the queue and execute an action depending on the message.

My problem is that when a massive amount of file is uploaded to the blob (~25 000), then the azure function open a lot of connection (ServiceBusClient) to send the messages to a  service bus queue which cause the service bus client to throw an error because I reach the [limit of connection (5000 max)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas#messaging-quotas). It means that my azure function have more than 5000 connections in parallel to the service bus.

Is there a way to limit the azure function to 2000 instances or to slow down the event send to the azure function ?

I already tried to make a retry policy if it fails inside the azure function and in the ServiceBusClient but i would really like to avoid this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to consider

**1. Use [Static Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients)**
This is probably the simplest approach since the idea is to just use one Service Bus client to ensure the same connection is used, instead of creating a new client for each invocation of the function app.

**2. Forward Events to Service Bus and setup Concurrency**
Instead of directly delivering events to your function app, you would [deliver them to a Service Bus queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-service-bus) and trigger a function from there.

This lets you set up [concurrency controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-concurrency) to limit how many messages are being processed at a time.